# Searching for posts with specific tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I allow my users to follow certain categories and other objects on my platform. For example, each category in this system has a unique `tag_id` (shown in brackets).

```
Billiards (1)
    Pool (2)
        9-Ball (3)
        8-Ball (4)
    Snooker (5)
Cycling (6)
    Mountain Biking (7)
        Cross Country (8)
        Downhill (9)
        Dual Slalom (10)
        Trials (11)
    Road Racing (12)
    Velodrome (13)
```

If a user wants to follow `Cycling > Mountain Biking > Downhill`, I will save `9`, `7`, and `6` to a `user_tags` table:

**user_tags**

```
user_id  | tag_id
---------|-----------
1        | 9
1        | 7
1        | 6
```

This means that if somebody posts something in just `Cycling (6)`, to reach all cyclists regardless of type, then it'll reach the user following `Downhill`.

Now, I have `feed` and `feed_tags` tables that contain all the posts and the tags they're associated with:

**feed**

```
feed_id  | title              
---------|------------------------------------------
1044     | How to get into cross country racing.
1045     | How to get into downhill racing.
```

**feed_tags**

```
feed_id  | tag_id
---------|----------
1044     | 8
1044     | 7
1044     | 6
1045     | 9
1045     | 7
1045     | 6
```

And now need to search the `feed` table for items that interest the user based on the associated tags.

**My attempt:**

First, I'm getting a result set of user's tags and caching it to speed things up for each search:

```
SELECT tag_id FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = 1;
```

This gets me the following:

```
tag_id
---------
9
7
6
```

I'm then looping through the user's tags model to build the joins part of the feed search query:

```
SELECT f.title
FROM feed AS f
// loop start
INNER JOIN feed_tags AS ft1 ON f.feed_id = ft1.feed_id
    AND ft1.tag_id = 9
INNER JOIN feed_tags AS ft2 ON f.feed_id = ft2.feed_id
    AND ft2.tag_id = 7
INNER JOIN feed_tags AS ft3 ON f.feed_id = ft3.feed_id
    AND ft3.tag_id = 6
// loop end
```

This seems to work on the very little test data I have. The above query returns only one posts, 'How to get into downhill racing.' and the following return them both:

```
SELECT f.title FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN feed_tags AS ft1 ON f.feed_id = ft1.feed_id
    AND ft1.tag_id = 6
```

However, I am concerned that this is not the correct way of doing this. I'm concerned that if the user is following 100 tags, this method is not going to be efficient enough because it's a high-traffic area of the platform. I'm also thinking that there may be a better query that doesn't involve building a query in a loop and contains both queries in one, both grabbing user's tags and cross-referencing them.

**Is this method I've chosen an acceptable one or can it be improved? If so, how can it be improved and why?**

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8af4b9/31)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer this myself after changing the category system to a simpler version. Instead of allowing each tier in the category system to be followable, I made just the endpoints followable like this:

```
Cycling [+]
    Mountain Biking [+]
        Cross Country (8)
        Downhill (9)
        Dual Slalom (10)
        Trials (11)
```

Which makes the following query work:

```
SELECT
  f.feed_id,
  f.title
FROM feed AS f
LEFT JOIN feed_tags AS ft ON ft.feed_id = f.feed_id
WHERE ft.tag_id IN (
  SELECT
    tag_id
  FROM user_tags
  WHERE user_id = 1
)
GROUP BY f.feed_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT f.title
FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN feed_tags AS ft1 ON f.feed_id = ft1.feed_id AND ft1.tag_id in (9,7,6)
```

You could also put the

```
SELECT tag_id FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = 1;
```

inside the `in` statement unless you are using it in other places also.

Answer (score -1):

[demo on dbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f4d6uDnVR869mgis15LaDJ/0)

the result you are getting is on the basis of **user_id 1** and **tag_id 9** only.
so, for a particular user_id, you are getting the **max of tag_id** and fetching the title from the feed table.

```sql
SELECT f.title
FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN feed_tags AS ft1 
    ON f.feed_id = ft1.feed_id 
    where ft1.tag_id = (
  SELECT max(tag_id) FROM user_tags WHERE user_id = 1
);
```

above query is for one user_id. 
If you have different user_id and then you want titles-use below query

```sql
SELECT f.title,ft1.tag_id
FROM feed AS f
INNER JOIN feed_tags AS ft1 
    ON f.feed_id = ft1.feed_id 
    where ft1.tag_id IN (
  SELECT max(tag_id) FROM user_tags WHERE user_id IN (1,2,3) group by user_id
);
```

Comment: Hi Nitika. Thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. It fails on `max(tag_id)`. If the user follows `Billiards (1) > Pool (2) > 8-Ball (4)` too, only the record with the highest tag_id gets shown.

Answer (score -2):

```
$search_data = $_REQUEST['search']; //your search keyword 

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user_name","db_user_password","db_name"); //connect your MySQL database

$select_data = "SELECT * FROM all_posts WHERE post_tag  LIKE '%$search_data%'"; //your search data select on your database 

$select = mysqli_query($connect,$select_data); //your search data

$search_array = mysqli_fetch_array($select); //your search data convert to array
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is nowhere near the correct solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jahid. I downvoted your answer because it doesn't solve the question in anyway. For future reference, it's a requirement that you explain your solution instead of just submitting code.